# ASP.NET store images directly in active memory

Tags: asp.net

Is there any performance advantage to storing images directly in application memory as opposed to on disk? I have an image handler currently which is as simple as:

```
image.ashx?imageid=XXX
```

Where XXX.jpg is stored on the filesystem.

Would storing the images in a dictionary in the applications memory offer any performance benefit?

```
public Dictionary(int imageid, byte[] imagedata)
```

The webserver has plenty of spare RAM going to waste.

Comment: Where is the bottleneck in your system? Do you have enough bandwidth to copy with the faster response from the server? Or is the bandwidth between server and client slower than the bandwidth between disk and HTTP Handler?

Comment: If you currently have no issues loading the images then I doubt you will gain noticeable performance by loading from memory. However, if there is a noticeable delay and you think that disk access is the problem then I would take the time to test the disk IO first. If you are going to cache, I would look at System.Web.Caching.Cache